# Drupal 9 CiviCRM not able to enable in windows

Tags: drupal-webform, drupal-9, civicrm

[image]

In Drupal 9 when we try to able the CiviCRM we are getting the above error.
We have tried with the below commands but this doesn't helped us

**attrib -r F:\wamp64\www\cidd\sites\default**

Comment: Unclear from your question but installing civicrm is not as simple as most drupal modules, and it would help if you explain what steps you followed. Some documentation here https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/

Comment: Also there is an SE specific for CiviCRM at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active